# Python execv and pipe output

Tags: python, process, pipe, fork, exec

I'd like to use Python's `os.execv` to replace my current process, but I also want the new process to send `stdout` to another process (to collect logs and ship them over the network). The process collecting logs also needs to be started by the original Python process.

I'm guessing I need to do some fork, dup2, execv stuff, but I need some help.

In bash, it might look something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
exec ./foo ∣ ./bar
```

Comment: the `subprocess` module can do this for you: https://gist.github.com/JacobIRR/dced5ce0f19e4f376aaef19d0e80d9d7

Comment: @JacobIRR That runs the command in a subprocess, it doesn't replace the current process.

Comment: Minor note, that doesn't quite do what you think it does in Bash - the main process follows the last stage of the pipeline, so the `exec` has no effect.

Comment: @ephemient thanks for the clarification. I guess that means I'm unsure how to do this in both Python and Bash!

Comment: The closest analogue in Bash would be with process substitution such as `exec ./foo > >(./bar)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up the pipe and processes this way.

```
import os

(read_fd, write_fd) = os.pipe()
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    os.dup2(read_fd, 0)
    os.close(read_fd)
    os.close(write_fd)
    os.execlp('./bar', './bar')
    os._exit(-1)  # in case exec fails
os.close(read_fd)
os.dup2(write_fd, 1)
os.close(write_fd)
os.execlp('./foo', './foo')
```

It's still convenient to use `subprocess` though, at least for the first part.

```
import os
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['./bar'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
os.dup2(p.stdin.fileno(), 1)
p.stdin.close()
os.execlp('./foo', './foo')
```